# Displaying specific HTML/Javascript elements from a website in a UIWebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I've done a decent bit of research on this but can't seem to find a definitive answer or implement it correctly. I'm currently building an iOS app that contains a UIWebView that loads a webpage. However, rather than displaying the whole webpage I'd like to just extract a certain element from it (in this case a form) and only display that in the WebView (forgetting all other elements like the header, footer etc.).

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `URLRequest` and store it in `NSString`. Trim unwanted content of this string and then in your `UIWebView` just call

`[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];`